# What is the strategy for Slip'n Slime?

Tags: tiny-heroes

I've got all levels with 3 stars, with the exception of Slip'n Slime which I have failed to crack. What is the strategy to play this level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here was my strategy to finally get all 3 stars on this challenge:

- **Work from the right side**. In the beginning, your starting Slime and Tentacles will take care of most heroes. Build as many Balistas as fast as possible on the right side (filling to the left) of the map, and keep that up throughout the level.
- Try to confuse Epic Clerics with the Lookers. If a Thief takes out a Perforator, try to replace it with a Ballista. (This stuff is not nearly as important as the other steps.)
- **Save the Fire Blast, Rock Drop and Lookers for those pesky Epic Rangers.** You can use them early on, but **don't** use them if the wave counter (in the upper left corner) is 3 or lower. Once the wave counter is gone (last wave), unleash a Fire Blast and a Rock Drop (one in each row), and then find those Ranger and drop the Looker on them. You'll probably still have some clean-up to do, but it shouldn't be a problem if you take out those Epic Rangers quickly.